# Not able to insert value into sqlite database

Tags: jquery, database, html, sqlite, cordova

I am trying to insert value into sqlite database but I am not able to get success. I am trying to add this value into cordova phonegap application. As this is meant to run as phone app in device so I have put alert in the function to check the flow of the function but unfortunately I am getting only one alert that too of entering into function. Later alerts I am not able to receive.

Here is the code.

```
function InsertMobileData(){
        myDB.transaction(function(transaction) {
            // Define insert query
            alert("In")
            var executeQuery = "INSERT INTO " +
                                "Mobile_Table" + 
                                "(device_PhoneNumber) "+
                                "VALUES(?)";
            Helper.log(executeQuery); 
            alert(callingNo);
            alert(executeQuery);
            transaction.executeSql(executeQuery, ['"+callingNo+"']
                , function(tx, result) {   // On success
                 alert("Mobile Number Inserted Successfully");
                },
                function(error){     // On error                               
                     alert("Error while inserting data");
                });
        });
}
```

Please help me to correct the code. Thanks.

Comment: did you get the result of `alert(callingNo);` and `alert(executeQuery);`?

Comment: @ekad I am getting only one alert message i.e `alert("In")`.After that i am not getting any alert messages..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is syntax error in your code here **"transaction.executeSql(executeQuery, ['"+callingNo+"']"**
You can try by this code its working...

```
function InsertMobileData(){
    myDB.transaction(function(transaction) {           
       var executeQuery = "INSERT INTO Mobile_Table (device_PhoneNumber) VALUES('"+callingNo+"')";
       transaction.executeSql(executeQuery, []
            , function(tx, result) {   // On success
             alert("Mobile Number Inserted Successfully");
            },
            function(error){     // On error                               
                 alert("Error while inserting data");
            });
    });      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a space after `"Mobile_Table" +` so it reads

```
var executeQuery =
  "INSERT INTO " +
  "Mobile_Table " + 
  "(device_PhoneNumber) "+
  "VALUES(?)";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think sql has no problem, you can use `insert into tablename(colname) values(theValue)`.

You have alert:

```
alert(callingNo);
```

But I didn't see the var callingNo. maybe there is an error here.